# Connect SSD with USB, install new Windows/Mac OS, and then replace hard drive; is that possible?

Tags: mac, windows-8, ssd

I just get my fist ssd and I wonder if I can install it in an easy way. So I want to connect the new SSD via USB to my computer, and install Windows or Mac OS first (so the SSD here is not the primary boot drive, just connected externally). And then I would replace my present hard drive with the SSD. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to install an OS onto an external drive.

You must swap the drives first then run off the installation disk.

Or you can use 3rd party software or DOS to copy your old hard drive to your new SSD so that you still have the same OS. Though that would take more time but it's still possible if you want to keep all your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I do this all of the time.

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Osx-Lion-on-an-External-Drive